# VUE render current date and time in cleanest way

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Wondering what would be the cleanest way to render the current date and time with VUE.
I know there is a lot of info about it  but the  code below does not show

I made a component to use:

```
export default {
  name: 'calendar',
  data() {
  today: "",
  },
  props: {
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default() {
        return new Date();
      },
    },
  },
};
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Search</router-link> <span></span>
      <router-link to="/about">Download</router-link>
      <online-offline/>
      </div>
     <navbar/>
    <calendar :date="date"/>
   <router-view />
</div>
</template>
<script>
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar.vue';
import OnlineOffline from '@/components/OnlineOffline.vue';
import Calendar from '@/components/Calendar.vue';
import moment from 'moment';

export default {
  components: { Navbar, OnlineOffline, Calendar },
  name: 'app',
```

`this.today = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')`  does not work either.

Thanks

Comment: The date is sent by props and does not change in the component right? you can use a filter to format the date https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Comment: Not sure this the problem, but normally when you define 'data' as a function in a component, you need to return an object: data() { return { today: '' } }